central character of the representation of an affine Hecke algebra
At the moment, I am studying affine Hecke algebras and for this I am reading Maarten Solleveld's paper "Affine Hecke Algebras and their Representation Theory" which is freely available here. As concerns the notation, $\mathcal{H} := \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{R}, \lambda , \lambda^*,q)$ is the affine Hecke algebra attached to the based root system $\mathcal{R} = (X, R, Y, R^{\vee}, \Delta)$, parameter functions $\lambda, \lambda^*$, and parameter $q\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and   $\mathcal{H}^P$ is the parabolic subalgebra corresponding to a subset $P$ of the basis $\Delta$.  Now in order to state the Langlands classification (theorem 3.13) we need to define what it means for an irreducible $\mathcal{H}^P$-representation $(\rho , V)$ to be in positive position. This involves the central character $cc(\rho) $ of $\rho$ (which exists by finite-dimensionality and irreducibility of $V$). The part I don't understand is how we can view $cc(\rho)$ as an element of $T/W$, where $T=\hom (X, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$ is a torus and $W$ is the Weyl group of $\mathcal{R}$.
Namely, if $\pi$ is any finite-dimensional $\mathcal{H}$-representation with set of weights $Wt (\pi)$, Solleveld states on p.26

Recall that the centre of $\mathcal{H}$ is $Z(\mathcal{H}) = \mathbb{C}[X]^W $. Hence, whenever a representation $\pi$ admits a central character $cc(\pi)$, we have $cc(\pi) = W Wt(\pi)\in T/W$.

For sure, any weight $t$ of $V$ coincides with $cc(\pi)$ when restricted to the centre $\mathbb{C}[X]^W$ of $\mathcal{H}$, but away from there, I don't see why two different weights $t$ and $s$ of $\pi$ in $T$ should lie in the same coset of $T/W$ (i.e. are "connected" by some $w\in W$). As far as see, there is only a (well-defined) map $T/W\to \hom (\mathbb{C}[X]^W, \mathbb{C})$, $Wt\mapsto t|_{\mathbb{C}[X]^W}$ and no map in the other direction, but I am sure I'm missing something... so any help is appreciated!

heck.............

The torus T is defined to be $\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb G_m)$, which, since $X$ has finite rank, is canonically isomorphic to $X^\vee \otimes \mathbb G_m \cong Y\otimes \mathbb G_m$. Thus
$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{Hom}(T,\mathbb G_m) &= \mathrm{Hom}(Y\otimes \mathbb G_m,\mathbb G_m)\\
& \cong \mathrm{Hom}(Y,\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb G_m,\mathbb G_m))\\
&= Y^\vee \cong X
\end{split}
$$
It follows that $\mathcal O(T) = \mathbb C[X]$, the group algebra of $X$. The centre of $Z(\mathcal H)$ is equal to $\mathbb C[X]^W$ and if $\iota\colon \mathbb C[X]^W \to \mathbb C[X]$ then $\iota$ corresponds to the pull-back on functions of the quotientr morphism $i\colon T \to T/W$, where $T/W = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C[X]^W)$ is the affine quotient of the torus by the action of the Weyl group. (Since $W$ is finite, the points of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C[x]^W)$ correspond to orbits of $W$ in $T$).
Now if $(V,\rho)$ is a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathcal H$ the $Z(\mathcal H)$ acts by scalars on $V$, so that $\rho_{|Z(\mathcal H)} = cc(\rho)\colon Z(\mathcal H) \to \mathbb C.\text{id}_V$. Thus if $\lambda \in \mathbb C[X]$ and $v \in V$ is a simultaneous eigenvector for the algebra $\mathbb C[X]$ we will have $\lambda(v) = \lambda(t_0).v$ for some $t_0 \in T$, where $t_0$ corresponds to the maximal ideal of $\mathbb C[X]$ consisting of those $f \in \mathbb C[X]$ for which $f(v)=0$.
The central character of $(V,\rho)$ is then $W.t_0 \in T/W$. To see why one might expect to get elements of $W.t_0$ arising as simultaneous eigenvalues for $\mathbb C[X]$ it may be useful to consider the setting of the affine Weyl group, which is analogous but simpler to the case of $\mathcal  H$. If we let $\hat{W} = W_0\ltimes \mathbb C[X]$ where $W_0$ is the finite Weyl group, and $(V,\rho)$ a finite-dimensional irreducible representations of $\hat{W}$, then if $v \in V$ is a simulataneous eigenvector for the commutative subalgebra $\mathbb C[X]$, we have $\lambda(v) = \lambda(t_0).v$ for all $\lambda \in X$ and some $t_0 \in T$. But then we have
$$
\lambda(w(v)) = w(w^{-1}\lambda w)(v)=w^{-1}(\lambda)(t_0)w(v) = \lambda(w(t_0))w(v).
$$

awesome, thank you!
